# CakePhp always redirecting to /users/login/

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am trying to auto login users based on query parameters but the session keeps expiring and users keeps getting redirected to `/users/login`

Here is my UsersController.php

```
public function login()
    {
        Log::config('InvalidSession', [
            'className' => 'File',
            'path' => LOGS,
            'levels' => ['debug'],
            'file' => 'InvalidSession',
        ]);
        // Log::debug($this->request);
        Log::debug($this->request['url']['redirect']);

        $url_components = parse_url($this->request['url']['redirect']);
        parse_str($url_components['query'], $params);

        $OfferwallId = $params['oid'];
        $UserId = $params['uid'];
        Log::debug('new login functionality Oid[' . $OfferwallId . '] Uid[' . $UserId . ']');


        $valid = true;

        if (empty($OfferwallId)) {
            $valid = false;
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid Offerwall'));
        }

        if (empty($UserId)) {
            $valid = false;
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid User'));
        }

        Log::debug('Valid['.$valid.']');
        if ($valid) {
            // Log::debug($this->request);
            //Log::debug($this->request['url']);

            $Offerwalls = TableRegistry::get('Offerwalls');
            $Offerwalls = $Offerwalls->find()->where(['Id' => $OfferwallId]);



            if (count($Offerwalls) == 0) {
                $valid = false;
                $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid Offerwall Id'));
            }



            if ($valid) {
                $Users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
                $conditions = array(
                    'UserId' => $UserId,
                    'OfferwallId' => $OfferwallId,
                );
                if ($this->Users->exists($conditions)) {
                    $user = $Users->find()->where($conditions);
                    $user = $user->toArray();
                    $this->Auth->setUser($user);                    

                    Log::debug('Setting user , probably session as well and redirecting');
                    return $this->redirect(
                        array(
                            "controller" => "Users",
                            "action" => "surveys",
                            "oid" => $OfferwallId,
                            "uid" => $UserId,
                            "from" => "login_page"
                        )
                    );
                } else {

                    //redirect to registration

                    return $this->redirect(
                        array(
                            "controller" => "Users",
                            "action" => "registration",
                            "oid" => $OfferwallId,
                            "uid" => $UserId
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My App Controller.php

```
 public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
            'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
        ]);
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action'     => 'index'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'surveys'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'storage' => 'Session'
        ]);

        $IpAddress = $this->request->clientIp();
        $resultVpn = IpLog::LogIpAddress($IpAddress);



        if ($resultVpn['IsVpn'] == 1) {
            //if its a vpn then redirect to the error page .
            if (!(
                strtolower($this->request->params['controller']) == 'users'
                &&
                strtolower($this->request->params['action']) == 'vpnerror'
                )
                ||
                strtolower($this->request->params['controller']) == 'postback'
                ||
                strtolower($this->request->params['controller']) == 'api'
                ) {


                return $this->redirect(
                    array(
                        "controller" => "Users",
                        "action" => "vpnerror",
                        "oid" => 1,
                        "uid" => 1,
                        "email" => 1,
                        "ipaddress" =>  $IpAddress,
                        "countryname" => $resultVpn['CountryName'],
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }


    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        $this->Auth->allow(['registration', 'index' , 'UnsubscribeSurveyNotify']);
    }
```

And my app.php

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout'=>302400//in minutes
    ]
```

PS: I am loading this in an iframe. If I load the website directly it works fine but on an iframe it keeps redirecting to /users/login/

Following are the logs I am getting

```
2020-03-24 01:50:12 Debug: /users/surveys?oid=6&uid=118220773802600666858&from=index_page
2020-03-24 01:50:12 Debug: new login functionality Oid[6] Uid[118220773802600666858]
2020-03-24 01:50:12 Debug: Valid[1]
2020-03-24 01:50:12 Debug: Setting user , probably session as well and redirecting
2020-03-24 01:50:13 Debug: /users/surveys?oid=6&uid=118220773802600666858&from=login_page
2020-03-24 01:50:13 Debug: new login functionality Oid[6] Uid[118220773802600666858]
2020-03-24 01:50:13 Debug: Valid[1]
2020-03-24 01:50:13 Debug: Setting user , probably session as well and redirecting
2020-03-24 01:50:13 Debug: /users/surveys?oid=6&uid=118220773802600666858&from=login_page
2020-03-24 01:50:13 Debug: new login functionality Oid[6] Uid[118220773802600666858]
2020-03-24 01:50:13 Debug: Valid[1]
2020-03-24 01:50:13 Debug: Setting user , probably session as well and redirecting
2020-03-24 01:50:14 Debug: /users/surveys?oid=6&uid=118220773802600666858&from=login_page
2020-03-24 01:50:14 Debug: new login functionality Oid[6] Uid[118220773802600666858]
2020-03-24 01:50:14 Debug: Valid[1]
2020-03-24 01:50:14 Debug: Setting user , probably session as well and redirecting
2020-03-24 01:50:15 Debug: /users/surveys?oid=6&uid=118220773802600666858&from=login_page
2020-03-24 01:50:15 Debug: new login functionality Oid[6] Uid[118220773802600666858]
2020-03-24 01:50:15 Debug: Valid[1]
2020-03-24 01:50:15 Debug: Setting user , probably session as well and redirecting
2020-03-24 01:50:15 Debug: /users/surveys?oid=6&uid=118220773802600666858&from=login_page
2020-03-24 01:50:15 Debug: new login functionality Oid[6] Uid[118220773802600666858]
2020-03-24 01:50:15 Debug: Valid[1]
2020-03-24 01:50:15 Debug: Setting user , probably session as well and redirecting
2020-03-24 01:50:16 Debug: /users/surveys?oid=6&uid=118220773802600666858&from=login_page
2020-03-24 01:50:16 Debug: new login functionality Oid[6] Uid[118220773802600666858]
2020-03-24 01:50:16 Debug: Valid[1]
2020-03-24 01:50:16 Debug: Setting user , probably session as well and redirecting
2020-03-24 01:50:17 Debug: /users/surveys?oid=6&uid=118220773802600666858&from=login_page
2020-03-24 01:50:17 Debug: new login functionality Oid[6] Uid[118220773802600666858]
2020-03-24 01:50:17 Debug: Valid[1]
2020-03-24 01:50:17 Debug: Setting user , probably session as well and redirecting
2020-03-24 01:50:17 Debug: /users/surveys?oid=6&uid=118220773802600666858&from=login_page
2020-03-24 01:50:17 Debug: new login functionality Oid[6] Uid[118220773802600666858]
2020-03-24 01:50:17 Debug: Valid[1]
2020-03-24 01:50:17 Debug: Setting user , probably session as well and redirecting
```

and at the end I get hit but Too Many Requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. This website is hosted with another website and is being loaded in iframe. So the session is regenerated on every new request because of the referrer.

Hope it helps anyone.